# Position element midway between adjacent element and end of parent element

Tags: css

I've got the following markup. It's being delivered dynamically, I'm limited in what changes can be made to it.

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="stage">
        <span class="stageText">Hello World</span>
        <span class="icon">|</span>
    </div>

    <div class="stage">
        <span class="stageText">Hello</span>
        <span class="icon">|</span>
    </div>

    <div class="stage">
        <span class="stageText">Hi There</span>
        <span class="icon">|</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (not quite doing as required/described)

```
#container {
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display:table;
    width:445px;
}

.stage {
    display:table-cell;
    width:33.33333%;
}

.icon {
    width:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

I need to position the <span class="icon">|</span>'s midway between the end of the <span class="stageText">'s and the right boundary of the parent element. Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/jralston/vc6pzawk/

Any help or pointers very much appreciated.

Thank You

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comments for changes. Advantage of this technique is that you do not need to use javascript or change the html, just css.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc6pzawk/4/)**

```
#container {
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display:table;
    width:445px;
}

.stage {
    display:inline-block;/*instead of table-cell*/
    text-align: center;/*centers text*/
    float: left;/*float */
    width:33.33333%;
}

.icon {
    float: right;/*put icons left or right from text*/
    width:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I create this solution using pseudo-element `:after`:

```css
#container {
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display:table;
    width:445px;
}

.stage {
    display:table-cell;
    width:33.33333%;
}

.stage:after {
    content: "|";
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="stage">
        <span class="stageText">Hello World</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="stage">
        <span class="stageText">Hello</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="stage">
        <span class="stageText">Hi There</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, I always forget about `::after`! Great answer. I think is more correct than my response since it is decoration after all.

Comment: Hmmm, not quite right as far as I can see. The 25% is too arbitrary . E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/jralston/vc6pzawk/5/ thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an easy to do this in CSS but you can do it relatively easy through JS & jQuery:

```
$('.icon').each(function () {
    var $el = $(this),
        containerWidth = $el.parent().width(),
        contentWidth = $el.prev().width();

    $el.css('left', (contentWidth) + ((containerWidth - contentWidth) / 2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vc6pzawk/3/